# Add CSS for <kbd> tag in comment

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to add some CSS to decorate the `<kbd>` tag when used in a comment? (They work fine in questions and answers).

I make this mistake frequently:

[image: <kbd> tag in comments]

Comment: You can't use HTML in comments: that's why they're not showing up. If you want to be able to do that, that's another [meta-tag:feature-request] entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [AstroCB points out in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237925/add-css-for-kbd-tag-in-comment#comment779854_237925), you can't use any kind of HTML in the comments. Comments use a mini-Markdown parser with a very select few formatting options available.

You've probably heard that comments are second-class citizens. They're not supposed to draw a lot of extra attention away from the question and its answers. That's why *many* requests for additional formatting options in comments end up declined (like multi-line comments). Comments just aren't important enough to warrant the additional features required to allow user input formatting in them (considering they'd actually have to *allow* HTML in comments, which then requires them to strip out invalid HTML - right now they just convert them to HTML entities which is much simpler).